# Average number of descendant nodes in a complete and full binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

Given a complete and full binary tree with *n* nodes, what is the average number of descendants a node has? For example, the root node has *n* - 1 descendants and each leaf node has 0 descendants, but considering all nodes, what is the average?

Comment: Why downvoting this question; it is more interesting than many questions like "How do I convert an integer to a string in python?". Of course, the original poster could have told a little more about why hy/she is asking, what first ideas he/she previously had before asking, but I upvote it on my side (and I just tried to post an answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Let's change a little your question *for a short moment*: we call "descendants" will be the number of descendants **including** the node itself.

A leaf has 1 descendant, its parent has 3 descendants, then 7, then 15, etc. These numbers are of kind 2^k - 1 where k is the number of levels from the bottom of the tree (with k=1 fot the leaves).

For K levels, you have obviously 2^K-1 nodes in your tree; since you called this value *n*, you have n=2^K-1 and K=log2(n+1).

Still calling a descendant as I previously did (see later for your exact question), you have 1 descendant for 2^(K-1) nodes (the leaves), 3 descendants for 2^(K-2) nodes, ... until n descendants for 2^(K-K)=1 node.

The average number of descendants will be:

```
Sum(k=1,K,   2^(K-k) * (2^k-1) ) / n
```

According to your definition of the "descendants" (excluding the node itself) you have to substract 1:

```
Sum(k=1,K,   2^(K-k) * (2^k-1) ) / n - 1
```

And by replacing K, you get:

```
Sum(k=1,log2(n+1),    (2^k-1)(n+1) / 2^k ) / n - 1
```

With the program Pari-GP, I type:

```
f(n)=sum(k=1,round(log(n+1)/log(2)),  (2^k-1)*(n+1) / 2^k ) / n - 1
```

and I get:

```
f(1)=0
f(3)=2/3
f(7)=10/7
f(15)=34/15
```

which looks like [A036799(n)](http://oeis.org/A036799)/n. If the sequence is actually the same (I didn't check carefully), you could write the simpler expression (without the sum):

```
f(n)= ((log(n+1)/log(2)-2)*(n+1)+2)/n
```